# How to create LONGTEXTS with BAPI_QUALNOT_CREATE in SAP?

Tags: java, abap, jco, sap-erp

I am using BAPI_QUALNOT_CREATE in JCo to create a quality notification and it works. The only thing that does not work is the creation of LONGTEXTS.

I am using the following code:

```
JCoTable tblText = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("LONGTEXTS")
if (tblText == null) {
    throw new Exception("...")
}

def rowNo = 0
tblText.appendRows(meldungsTextLang.size())
for (String text : meldungsTextLang) {
    if (text != null && text.length() > 132) text = text.substring(0, 132)
    tblText.setRow(rowNo++)
    tblText.setValue("FORMAT_COL", "*")
    tblText.setValue("TEXT_LINE", text)
}
```

But the text never appears in the quality notification.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Just as an FYI, there are specific instructions for longtexts in the documentation of the BAPI.

Comment: i.e. OBJTYPE and OBJKEY components of LONGTEXTS must be filled according to the rules stated in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objtyp and objkey are not populated in the code which are mandatory therefore try below corrected code.

```
JCoTable tblText = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("LONGTEXTS")
if (tblText == null) {
    throw new Exception("...")
}

def rowNo = 0
tblText.appendRows(meldungsTextLang.size())
for (String text : meldungsTextLang) {
    if (text != null && text.length() > 132) text = text.substring(0, 132)
    tblText.setRow(rowNo++)
    tblText.setValue("OBJTYP","QMSM")
    tblText.setValue("OBJKEY","1")
    tblText.setValue("FORMAT_COL", "*")
    tblText.setValue("TEXT_LINE", text)
}
```

Comment: It's `OBJTYPE` with a final `E` (not `OBJTYP`/the documentation has a typo). `QMSM` is only for a notification "task", it could be other values depending on the parameter NOTIF_TYPE. Currently, we don't  know what type of notification SipCat wants to create.